# Why does in path I should use double backslashes but in glob pattern - quadruple?

Tags: java, io, path, escaping, glob

If I want to create instance of `Path` in java I should write something like this:

```
Paths.get("D:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3");
```

Thus I should use double backslashes

Also I can use single slash

```
Paths.get("D:/dir1/dir2/dir3");
```

If I want to write GLOB pattern I have following variants:

```
FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:D:/dir1/dir2/**");
```

or

```
FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:D:\\\\dir1\\\\dir2\\\\**");
```

I don't understand this escaping magic. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, `\` is used to specify escape characters in many languages. But not `/`.

Ex:
`\n` = newline
`\t` = tab

and

`\\` = `\`

In order to represent `\` in a string, you have to use `\\`. Hence, every time you use `\\`, it will be parsed as `\`.

EDIT :

in the `FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher()`, it needs a pattern. Patterns also does a parsing. In order to get `D:\dir1\dir2\**` as the intended path, you have to use `\\` in stead of `\`, and since it is specified as a pattern, each `\` of `\\` should be represented as `\\`. So in the end, each `\` is represented as `\\\\`.

Look for  [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) for more info,

Comment: This answer is not particularly helpful unless you explain why  `getPathMatcher("glob:D:\\dir1\\dir2\\**");` is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

As you are aware, in a regular expression one needs to escape a backslash in order to obtain a literal backslash: `\\ -> '\'`. In the `getPathMatcher()` method, backslashes are already used to escape special characters:

> The backslash character (`\`) is used to escape characters that would otherwise be interpreted as special characters.

So to produce a literal `'\\'`, you have to escape each backslash, resulting in `\\\\`. Confusing, no?